# How to eliminate piercing evolution alarm?

Tags: 20.04, evolution, calendar

When I have calendar events with reminders, I get an extremely loud *piercing* repeated high-pitched double beep.

This gods-awful sound **is not** any of the Gnome Desktop alarm sounds.

How do I eliminate this behavior without getting rid of alarms altogether?

**Edit:** Confirm this problem persists in 22.04.

Comment: This website suggests the sound is user modifiable, but I don't have it installed to check. https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/calendar-alarms-and-reminders.html.en